# How do you call the set function on a map's property?

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

Just like with other objects, you can call:

```
set('myKey', 44);
set('something', 'Hello World');
```

you can even do maps

```
set("myMap", new Map());
```

but how do i call set to notify if a map property has changed.  Obviously, i cant do:

```
set('myMap.myProp', 'test');
```

can i?

im trying to update the map property for something bound to the screen, but i thought it would be silly to do something like:

```
Map m = myMap;
m['myProp'] = 'test';
set('myMap',m);
```

since it is doing a lot of work it wouldnt need to do.

This is in PolymerDart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this

```
set('myMap.myProp', 'test');
```

should work fine to add an item to the map with key `myProp` and value `'test'`

Comment: so it does.  I thought it was going to be a goofy "cant do this" kinda thing.  Thanks

Comment: There is some JavaScriptism bleeding into our Dart world ;-)